# pass forwardRef via cloneElement reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const ref = useRef()  

 React.Children.map(this.props.children, (element) => {
   React.cloneElement(element, { 
     innerRef: node => ref,
   })
 })
```

here element is a component

like the following

```
const newComponent = forwardRef(({children, ...otherprops}, ref){
    return (
     <div {...otherprops} ref={otherprops.innerRef}>
       {children}
     </div>
    )        
})
```

getting `ref` is `null` in forwardRef...

Reproducible example :- https://codesandbox.io/s/forward-ref-cloneelement-1msjp

Comment: Please provide some producible example, also you using hooks with classes which are not likely to compile. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I noticed you updated the question, you can check my new answer tell me if it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing `innerRef` to `ref`, you adding `innerRef` property and expecting it to be valid at `ref`:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function RefForm(props) {
  const setRefs = useRef(new Map()).current;
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, child => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
//         v not innerRef
          ref: node => {
            console.log('imHere');
            return !node
              ? setRefs.delete(child.key)
              : setRefs.set(child.key, node);
          }
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default RefForm;
```

Then you can access the ref as you like:

```
const Email = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  console.log('email--', ref);
  ref(); // logs "imHere"
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
      <label>this is email</label>
      <input name="email" ref={props.innerRef} />
    </div>
  );
});
```

[image: Edit forward-ref-cloneelement]

### Edit:

For class components need to use [another key then `ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components).

> There is one caveat to the above example: refs will not get passed through. That’s because ref is not a prop. Like key, it’s handled differently by React. If you add a ref to a HOC, the ref will refer to the outermost container component, not the wrapped component.

```
// class component
class Name extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('name--', this.props.innerRef);

    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
        <label>this is name</label>
        <input name="name" ref={this.props.innerRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// functional component
const Email = props => {
  console.log('email--', props.innerRef);
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
      <label>this is email</label>
      <input name="email" ref={props.innerRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

// cloneElement
function RefForm(props) {
  const setRefs = useRef(new Map()).current;
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, child => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          innerRef: node => {
            return !node
              ? setRefs.delete(child.key)
              : setRefs.set(child.key, node);
          }
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-58803654-forwardRefInClass]

---

Further, read:

- [Why, exactly, do we need `React.forwardRef`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931842/7882470)

Comment: for class component ref is undefined, check here https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-http-ykb0b

Comment: With classes you need to use other keys like `innerRef`: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-58803654-forwardrefinclass-jve85, edited the answer

Comment: i have combination of both class and functional component in my form.. only way to set ref via `RefForm.js`

Comment: Check the sandbox, I made the example for both, and you can see it in the answer too

Comment: Why not? Elaborate, you see in both function and class I use `props.innerRef`. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wing-jve85?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: if i use `innerRef` in `React.forwardRef` then i will get the following warning ```Warning: forwardRef render functions accept exactly two parameters: props and ref. Did you forget to use the ref parameter?```

Comment: You don't need the `forwardRef` in case you using the prop, and how is it related to "it doesn't work" when it just a warning?

Comment: Here is the complete example, you can see that `Map` has both references although one is function and one is a class. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wing-jve85?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202894/discussion-between-dennis-vash-and-dhanush-bala).

Comment: @DennisVash do you know why this might had stopped working? not even printing the 'imHere' inside the function