# Get DOM Element of Current Component with React-DOM: NULL returned

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I was following [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/get-react-component-element) that says you can get the DOM element of the current component as `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)`.

But when I try this I get a NULL result in the `node` var:

```
export default function Component(props) {

    // Initialization
   useEffect(() => {
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    console.log(node); // NULL 
   }, []); 

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in function component since `this` not referring to component's instance like in class components. In function component you attaching `useRef` to the root component.

Comment: It even mentioned in docs "findDOMNode cannot be used on function components.", https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

Comment: So what's the correct way to get the DOM element of the Component itself in a functional component? any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findDOMNode` won't work in function component, aside from what is written in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) ("`findDOMNode` cannot be used on function components."), it has to do with the fact that function components don't have instances like classes, read carefully [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931842/7882470).

In function component, you get the current DOM element by attaching a ref to the root node:

```
export default function Component(props) {
  const nodeRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(nodeRef.current);
  }, []);

  // Root Node
  return <input ref={nodeRef} />;
}
```

Comment: How to access native DOM element from `ref` in functional components?

Comment: The ref already holds the native DOM element, just use it? https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs