# React forwardRef for function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref, react-forwardref

I have this interface:

```js
export interface INTERFACE1{
  name?: string;
  label?: string;
}
```

and then this function component:

```js
export function FUNCTION1({
  name,
  label
}: INTERFACE1) {
  return (
    <CustomComponent name={name} label={label} />
  );
}
```

my goal is to access this `CustomComponent` from another component. I tried adding `ref: React.createRef<any>` inside the interface but it didn't click in. From my research, it seems that I need to use `forwardRef` but most of the online examples don't seem to work. Any ideas how can I reference my `CustomComponent` from outside, from different component, like this?

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState, createRef } from 'react';
import { FUNCTION1 } from 'FUNCTION1';

interface INTERFACE2 {
  loading: boolean;
}

export default function FUNCTION2({
  loading
}: INTERFACE2) {
  const areaRef = createRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>();

  return (
    <>
          <FUNCTION1
            name="NAME"
            label="LABEL"
            ref={areaRef}
          />
    </>
  );
}
```

`areaRef` throws an error that I should use `forwardRef`.

Comment: What does it mean "access from another component", sounds like [the XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please show a full example of what you trying to achieve, an example of you trying to "access" your component, and use it will be helpul.

Comment: I edited my question, I added an example how is my intention to access the component through ref from another component. @DennisVash

Comment: Your example isn't clear enough. And what exactly are you trying to achieve. Trying to use ref might not be the appropriate way of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a `forwardRef` here, please refer to: [Why, exactly, do we need React.forwardRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62931216/why-exactly-do-we-need-react-forwardref/62931842#62931842).

In your specific example:

- Don't UPPER CASE your component name, its should only start with Capital
- Pass your ref through any prop, see explanation in link above.
- Use a hook `useRef` in function components, `createRef` is for classes.

```
function Foo2() {
  const areaRef = useRef();

  // Check ref
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(areaRef.current);
  }, []);

  return <CustomComponent inneRef={areaRef} />;
}

function CustomComponent({ innerRef }) {
  return <textArea ref={innerRef} />;
}
```